# Use scientific notation only if needed

Tags: c#, string-formatting, number-formatting

I want to parse a `double` value into a `string`. I want my number to have a specified number of digits (that I won't know until runtime). If this number can be expressed with a non-zero value in number of digits this is what I want. If the number comes out as zero's like this I want it expressed in scientific notation.

Some examples will make this more clear, this assumes I wanted 3 digits:

**Value:** .2367 **Output:** "0.23"

**Value:** .00367 **Output:** "3.67E-3"

**Value:** 22.3 **Output:** "22.3"

**Value:** 3364.0 **Output:** "3.36E3"

My work around solution would use the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad.aspx) method and the `N` [numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and if it results in zero's revert to the `E` format string, but this feels like reinventing the wheel. Does anyone know if a built in method to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you want 2.37E-1 for the first one?

Comment: Actually my preference would be to only use the scientific notation if all the values were 0, but either way would suffice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [General Number Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#GFormatString)?

> The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the most
>   compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the
>   type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present.

Some samples from the documentation:

```
double number;

number = .0023;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 0.0023

number = 1234;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("G2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1.2E+03

number = Math.PI;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("G5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 3.1416
```

Comment: I don't know how I managed to overlook this in the documentation.